# How can I make this a multilevel navbar with nested elements?

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, dropdown

I have a hamburger menu on my website and I would like to add some multilevel functionality to it. It stretches across the width of the page and clicking the hamburger button expands a dropdown of links directly under it. I want some of those links to have their own dropdowns as well. I can't get the nested dropdowns to display properly. How can I add nested links to the dropdown list?

Something like the following:

- Link 1
- Link 2

  - Link A
  - Link B

    - Link C
- Link 3

Below is my current relevant code. Thanks in advance for any and all help.

```
<section class="top-nav">
  <div></div>
  <input id="menu-toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class='menu-button-container' for="menu-toggle">
    <div class='menu-button'></div>
    <span style="position: absolute; margin-left: 5em; font-size: 1.5em;">MENU</span>
  </label>
  <a>Login</a>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a>Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

```
.top-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #FFF;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 99;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

.menu > li {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);;
}

.menu-button-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -19em;
}

#menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}

.menu-button,
.menu-button::before,
.menu-button::after {
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0.2em;
  width: 2em;
  transition: transform 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  border-radius: 2em;
}

.menu-button::before {
  content: '';
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.menu-button::after {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#menu-toggle:checked + .menu-button-container .menu-button::before {
  margin-top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(405deg);
}

#menu-toggle:checked + .menu-button-container .menu-button {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#menu-toggle:checked + .menu-button-container .menu-button::after {
  margin-top: 0px;
  transform: rotate(-405deg);
}

#menu-toggle ~ .menu li {
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  transition: height 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
#menu-toggle:checked ~ .menu li {
  height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  transition: height 400ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
```

EDIT: I updated my HTML code because I realized it wasn't working properly when pasting in CodePen. It still doesn't perfectly match what I have on my actual webpage but I think it's close enough to demonstrate what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome, Jerry :D hope you find stackoverflow more welcoming and informative for you ^^.

I didn't really understand what you want exactly it would be helpful if you used a codepen space to show us a demo using https://pen.new

So to achieve that hierarchal shape we use a trick
ul
li
li
ul
li
li
ul
li

I hope you understood what I am referring to
so the code is going to be something like this :

```
<ul> 
  <li> Hello </li>
  <li> Hello </li>
  <li > Title </li>
  <ul > 
    <li> Hello2 </li> 
    <li> Hello2 </li> 
    <li> Hello2 </li> 
    <ul> <li> Hello3 </li> 
      <li> Hello3 </li> 
      <li> Hello3 </li> 
    </ul> </ul> 
  <li> Hello </li> 
  <li> Hello </li> 
  <li> Hello </li> 
</ul>
```

To make every title of them a dropdown itself you may achieve that we are going to hide all children, and only show them if the title has hovered or themselves have hovered.
a working example will be found [here](https://codepen.io/abdootolba/pen/YzOMGpO)
Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! I apologize for the late reply, but this is essentially what I'm looking for. So, thank you! I'll also be sure to post the codepen next time. I do have one question regarding your code, how would I modify that so the nested menus only appear when the parent is clicked instead of a hover?

Comment: You are welcome bro , please don't forget to highlight the answer if it is the one satisfies your question 

To make it show only when you click you may do it in 2 best ways, The first one is using CSS only, it is more complex but I like it
The other one needs js.
which do you like to start with?

Comment: Marked! If JS is simpler, then that solution is fine with me. Thank you!